# Splitting a string to get a number

Tags: ruby

I want to grab a number from a list of scores e.g. `"Score:5"` or `"Score:10"`.

I can't find a way to grab the number and turn it into an int so I can use it for an array. Any help?

My code as follows looks for a score that contains a number

```
range = 0
array = []
Dir["C:/Users/Cam/Desktop/warmup/Warmup_tally/*"].each do |filename|
  File.open(filename) do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      if line.include? "Score"
        puts line.split(':')
        range += 1
        array.push(-0, "#{line}") 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but I want to only grab that number and put it inside `Array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume your array is

```
a=["Score:5","Score:10","Score:11"]
```

Code

```
p a.map{|x| x[/\d+/].to_i}
```

output

```
[5, 10, 11]
```

**Update**

I have taken your inner code and corrected it

```
if line.include? "Score"
   array.push line[/\d+/].to_i
end
```

Or

```
array.push line[/\d+/].to_i if line.include? "Score"
```

Now print the array, output contains only the score numbers.

Comment: I forgot to add my code my bad, I tried that but it gave a regexp error
error: in `[ ] ': no implicit conversion of Regexp into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: You could also do this with `f.each_line.map { ... }` surrounding that `map` call to minimize the code.

Comment: @Ebonite6 Updated , check it now.

Comment: My bad, I was actually adding strings into the array so the error was on me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Instead of a conditional `push`, consider using `select` to filter. In this case `grep` is even better since you can use a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Could you just split on the `:` character? Something like this:

```
prefix, score = "Score:5".split(':')
# => ["Score", "5"]
```

Then you could just do `score.to_i` if you need it to be an integer.